# Problem in decoding Base64 encoded wchar_t* in plain C

Tags: c, windows, base64

I am having trouble finding a working implementation in C (not C++) to decode a wchar_t* encoded Base64.

I've tried creating my own implementation by modifying existing ones but it doesn't seem to work either.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>

wchar_t* base64_decode(const wchar_t* encoded)
{
    const wchar_t base64_chars[] = L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    const size_t encoded_len = wcslen(encoded);
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    int padding = 0;
    if (encoded_len < 4 || encoded_len % 4 != 0)
        return NULL;
    if (encoded[encoded_len - 1] == L'=')
        padding++;
    if (encoded[encoded_len - 2] == L'=')
        padding++;
    const size_t decoded_len = ((encoded_len / 4) * 3) - padding;
    wchar_t* decoded = (wchar_t*)malloc((decoded_len + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    if (!decoded)
        return NULL;
    while (i < encoded_len)
    {
        uint32_t sextet_a = encoded[i] == L'=' ? 0 & i++ : base64_chars[wcschr(base64_chars, encoded[i++]) - base64_chars];
        uint32_t sextet_b = encoded[i] == L'=' ? 0 & i++ : base64_chars[wcschr(base64_chars, encoded[i++]) - base64_chars];
        uint32_t sextet_c = encoded[i] == L'=' ? 0 & i++ : base64_chars[wcschr(base64_chars, encoded[i++]) - base64_chars];
        uint32_t sextet_d = encoded[i] == L'=' ? 0 & i++ : base64_chars[wcschr(base64_chars, encoded[i++]) - base64_chars];
        uint32_t triple = (sextet_a << 3 * 6)
                        + (sextet_b << 2 * 6)
                        + (sextet_c << 1 * 6)
                        + (sextet_d << 0 * 6);
        if (j < decoded_len)
            decoded[j++] = (triple >> 2 * 8) & 0xFF;
        if (j < decoded_len)
            decoded[j++] = (triple >> 1 * 8) & 0xFF;
        if (j < decoded_len)
            decoded[j++] = (triple >> 0 * 8) & 0xFF;
    }
    decoded[j] = L'\0';
    return decoded;
}
```

```
int main() 
{
        wchar_t* decoded_string = base64_decode(L"c3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdw=="); // "stackoverflow"
        std::wcout << decoded_string; // wrong no-sense output ("stackoverflow" expected)
}
```

Whats wrong in my implementation?

Does anyone has a working/better implementation in plain C for Windows (**no external libraries**)?

Thanks.

Comment: Base64 is a *family* of encodings.  Your decoder needs to match the specific member of that family with which the data were encoded.

Comment: Also, the details and significance of `wchar_t` are implementation specific.  It's an integer data type of a particular (implementation-specific) size, and how values of this type correspond to characters (i.e. the encoding) is implementation specific and likely locale dependent.

Comment: Is there another (maybe easier) way to decode a base64 string?

Comment: You can't claim your code is not C++ nd then use `std::wcout << decoded_string;`!

Comment: Well i was referring to the `base64_decode` method :)

Comment: Using `wchar_t` to handle Base64 seems perverse — unless `wchar_t` is an 8-bit type.  The point behind Base64 encoding is to encode groups of 3 arbitrary bytes as 4 bytes which contain only safe printable 8-bit characters.

Comment: Right now, I'm having trouble understanding the point.  Base-64 is a *binary to binary* encoding, where encoded data use only bytes that correspond printable ASCII characters.  Sure, you could treat encoded byte sequences as wide strings, but then you no longer have an assurance of printable characters.  Or you can convert the encoded bytes to `wchar_t` on a per-byte basis, but then you (probably) change the moderate data size expansion inherent in Base64 into a huge one.